# c# updating database problem

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to update a set of data onButtonClick . 
i have  a username , date of birth ,
with CurrentEmailAddress, NewEmailAdrress, ConfirmNewEmailAddress

Im trying to update all of them on a single click. I am able to update the username , but i couldnt update the date of birth and email address.

Below is my c# code: 
do note that myDBmanager is to execute the update and it has no problem

```
 //SQL query
        string updateSQL = "UPDATE user_profile,user_login SET ";
        updateSQL += "user_profile.user_name = '" + txtUserName.Text + "', ";
        updateSQL += "user_profile.user_dob = '" + txtDateOfBirth.Text + "'";


            if (txtNewPassword.Text != " " && txtNewEmailAddress.Text == " ")
            {
                updateSQL += ", user_login.user_passw = '" + txtNewPassword.Text + "'";
            }
            else if (txtNewPassword.Text == " " && txtNewEmailAddress.Text != " ")
            {
                updateSQL += ", user_profile.user_email = '" + txtNewEmailAddress.Text + "'";

            }
            else if (txtNewPassword.Text != " " && txtNewEmailAddress.Text != " ")
            {
                updateSQL += ", user_login.user_passw = '" + txtNewPassword.Text + "',";
                updateSQL += "user_profile.user_email = '" + txtNewEmailAddress.Text + "'";
            }
            else { }

            updateSQL += " WHERE user_profile.user_profile_id = 1 ";
            updateSQL += " AND user_login.user_profile_id = 1 ;";
            updateSQL += Global.myDBManager.GetNewIndex();

            int update = Global.myDBManager.ExecuteSql(updateSQL);



        //Close connection
        Global.myDBManager.Disconnect();
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: You really really really want to use command parameters. Building sql queries via string concatenation from user input **IS EVIL**.

Comment: Can you post the full SQL that you're executing in the question, I think that may help us come up with an answer. I find your code a little strange, why are you checking the password field in each if statement? That seems odd. And the last else {} doesn't do anything.

Comment: Second @ChrisWue, string concat is the recipe for SQL injection hacks (granted this may be a WinForms app, but it's still a bad practice, stay clear).

Comment: `updateSQL += " AND user_login.user_profile_id = 1 ;";` Notice the double ";" and then you add `updateSQL += Global.myDBManager.GetNewIndex();` Thus, you are actually running 2 queries (?). Anyways, what does GetNewIndex() do?

Comment: @foo ming xiang - What error its throwing, it must not be executing only part of the query, to do partial update.

Comment: What does your final `updateSQL` string contain, that would help know what is being executed

Comment: there is no error. Just that it does not update anything at all. where the updateSQL doesnt show anything at all when i put it in the IF statement.

Comment: Parts of the code is outside the if statement, so updateSQL must be something. Can you set a breakpoint at "int update = Global..." and copy the value of updateSQL and add to your question.

Comment: And this is actually the full SQL statement that i have. 

It is to update the username, user_dob and email address.

and for the updateSQL += Global.myDBManager.GetNewIndex(); it does not matter and i have removed it.

Comment: Use SQL profiler to see exactly what SQL query is being executed when you call this met.hod, it can help find the problem in SQL query.

Comment: But can you show the exact value that the string updateSQL has right before it gets executed? We have already seen your code, but if we get the SQL string then we can see what part of your logic is wrong (which I think is the error here).

Comment: @Askwani-K, he has it tagged as mySQL, SQL Profiler is for MS SQL Server.

Comment: here's my updateSQL when i dint not enter anytihng into email and password textbox. UPDATE user_profile,user_login SET user_profile.user_name = 'abcdefghisad', user_profile.user_gender = 'F', user_profile.user_country = 'MO' WHERE user_profile.user_profile_id = 1 AND user_login.user_profile_id = 1 ;

Comment: However , when i enter some text in email or password textbox. the debugging doesnt CATCH anything at all. Its like it got stuck in somewhere.

Comment: There's nothing in the code that would stuck, at least not in the posted code. I suggest you play with break points until you can get the real SQL (from updateSQL), from the scenario where you're having problems. It's very odd that the SQL you posted include things like user_gender and country, when your code above does not have any references like that. We all want to help, but you need to put in the effort to provide details and be accurate in your description of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen to the comments in this question - what you are doing, aside from not actually working for you, is very dangerous, and ripe for SQL Injection attacks. Google for "sql injection c#" and implement a solution - this article looks good:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlInjectionAttacks.aspx

Once you've fixed that, you probably had/have some sort of simple code bug that is preventing your code from working, because your method (aside from the vulnerabilities) doesn't look too bad.

Stick a breakpoint on the top of the method, and work through the method, making sure the sql string is being built up as expected.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For checking empty string, use

```
!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNewPassword.Text)
```

instead of

```
txtNewPassword.Text != " "
```

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: Very good practice to use that instead yes (if he's using .NET 4)

Comment: yes im using it but i got a error saying that Error 10 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'

Comment: It's new for .NET 4. You can use IsNullOrEmpty, but it won't trim whitespace for you, so you have to do that manually.